# Count object property inside array using lodash or vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have this object with nested arrays/objects:

```
{
"USA": [
    {
        "location": "New York",
        "municipality": "Manhattan",
    },
    {
        "location": "Texas",
        "municipality": "Austin",
    }
  ],
"CANADA": [
    {
        "location": "Ontario",
        "municipality": "no municipality",
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to use lodash or plain javascript to count how many `location` are inside the `USA` and `CANADA`. How is that possible?

desired result:

```
USA: 2
CANADA: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the array lengths:

```js
var USA = myObj.USA.length;
var Canada = myObj.CANADA.length;
```

Or, for larger data sets:

```
var result = {};
Object.keys(myObj)
    .forEach(function(key,index) {
        result[key] = myObj[key].length;
    });
```

Comment: i want to iterate, the array has ~400 objects

Comment: @StathisNtonas: Added an example for that.

Answer (score 3):

With lodash you could use [**mapValues**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues):

```
let result = _.mapValues(data, 'length');
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `Array.prototype.reduce()` function:

```js
var obj = {
        "USA": [ { "location": "New York", "municipality": "Manhattan" }, { "location": "Texas", "municipality": "Austin" } ], "CANADA": [ { "location": "Ontario", "municipality": "no municipality" }] 
    },

    result = Object.keys(obj).reduce(function(r,k){
        r[k] = obj[k].length;
     return r;
    }, {});

console.log(result)
```